# troubleshooting custom javafx listview cell

Tags: java, javafx

Listview cells loading blank instead of custom cell

I've tried rebuilding fxml file, using debug tools, none of these have helped.I've looked extensively on the net but can only find guides for older versions of javafx listview.

Before some tells me that the updateItem code is wrong, please just help me get it working first, then at least it'll be somewhere to start from for optimizing it

```
package Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class ListCellController2 extends ListCell<Student>
{
    FXMLLoader loader;

    @FXML
    private Glyph attendenceSymbolGlyph;
    @FXML
    private Label studentDetailsLabel;
    @FXML
    private Pane entryPane;

   @Override
   protected void updateItem(Student student, boolean empty)
   {
       super.updateItem(student, empty);

       if (empty || student == null)
       {
           setText(null);
           setGraphic(null);
       }
       else
       {
           loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ListCell2.fxml"));
           try
           {
               loader.load();
               studentDetailsLabel.setText(student.toString());
               setGraphic(entryPane);
           }
           catch (IOException ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph?>

<Pane fx:id="entryPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Test.ListCellController2">
   <children>
      <Glyph id="attendenceSymbolGlyph" fx:id="attendenceSymbolGlyph" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="87.0" />
      <Label id="studentDetailsLabel" fx:id="studentDetailsLabel" layoutX="113.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="88.0" prefWidth="482.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

```
package Test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ListView<Student> myListView;
    public ObservableList<Student> studentList;

    public MainController() 
    {
        studentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        studentList.add(new Student("Jimmy", "u0764987", "ef937b3"));
        studentList.add(new Student("John", "u0762809", "543jh32"));
    }

    public void setupListView()
    {
        try
        {
            myListView.setItems((ObservableList)studentList);
            myListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Student>, ListCell<Student>>()
            {
                @Override
                public ListCell<Student> call(ListView<Student> p) 
                {
                    return new ListCellController();
                }

            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) 
    {
        if (!studentList.isEmpty())
        {
            setupListView();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("student list is empty");
        }
    }

}
```

My expected result would be that it loads my data into the custom cell then displays it, what it actually does is is give me a blank cell

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. Also unrelated: don't load the cell ui in every call to update item, instead load it once and configure it later

Comment: You posted `ListCellController2`, but the `cellFactory` uses `ListCellController`. We cannot help you if the relevant code is not available. [Edit] the question and add the missing code. Furthermore recreating nodes every time `updateItem` is called should be avoided. Reuse nodes, if possible.

Comment: Thank you to @Jochen for answering the question. kleopatra, fabian it sounds like the two you don't remember what it's like trying to use something new and strugling to work out why it doesn't work. You're very quick I feel to criticize others, This is the minimal code since all I was trying to achieve was to get a listview to use and show a custom cell, the fact that it says ListCellController instead of ListCellController2 is resultant from me screwing around so much trying to get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you created two instances of your `ListCellController2`  class.

- you create the first instance in your list view cell factory
- the second instance is created when you load the FXML as the controller class is given inside the FXML

I also suggest you only load the list cell component once when your cell is created, instead of every time a new value is shown.

The controller is created by the cell factory and the instance is used by the FXML-loader. This way, the fields annotated with `@FXML` get initialized correctly.

Here is my code:

## MainController.java

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ListView<Student> myListView;
    public ObservableList<Student> studentList;

    public MainController() {
        studentList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        studentList.add(new Student("Jimmy", "u0764987", "ef937b3"));
        studentList.add(new Student("John", "u0762809", "543jh32"));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        if (!studentList.isEmpty()) {
            setupListView();
        } else {
            System.out.println("student list is empty");
        }
    }
    
    private void setupListView() {
        myListView.setItems(studentList);
        myListView.setCellFactory((listView) -> new ListCellController2());
    }
}
```

## ListCellController2

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class ListCellController2 extends ListCell<Student> {

    @FXML
    private Glyph attendenceSymbolGlyph;
    @FXML
    private Label studentDetailsLabel;
    @FXML
    private Pane entryPane;

    public ListCellController2() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ListCell2.fxml"));
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Creating UI component failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Student student, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(student, empty);

        if (empty || student == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            studentDetailsLabel.setText(student.toString());
            setGraphic(entryPane);
        }
    }
}
```

## ListCell2.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph?>

<Pane fx:id="entryPane" prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Glyph id="attendenceSymbolGlyph" fx:id="attendenceSymbolGlyph" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="87.0" />
      <Label id="studentDetailsLabel" fx:id="studentDetailsLabel" layoutX="113.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="88.0" prefWidth="482.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```